how do I set the pie color with pychartjs?
How do I add colors to pie chart with pychartjs?
chartjs has an example where it does the following:
backgroundColor: colorize.bind(null, false, false),
How can colorize be used in the python code below?
class newPieChart(BaseChart):

def setData(self, _data: dict):
    self.data.data = [10,20,30]
    return

def setLabels(self, _labels: list):
    self.labels.labels = ['A','B','C']
    return

type = ChartType.Pie

class labels:
    labels = []

class data:
    data = []

Then create a new pie chart:
NewChart = Chart1(case)

ChartJSON = NewChart.get()

